# Should we allow questions that ask for (useful, concrete) naming suggestions?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on a programming language that has two related concepts that are important, common, and subtly different. Think *function* vs *procedure,* or *panic* vs *exception*. I'd like help from the community coming up with good names, or telling me they are known elsewhere as X and Y.

Here's a similar question from the subreddit: [How to name both functions and variables with one term?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/14rc8yc/how_to_name_both_functions_and_variables_with_one/) (answer: "symbol").

**Are questions asking for naming suggestions ok?** I'm assuming here the questions are for well-defined, useful concepts. Not "what should I name my language", [not asking for the definition of existing names](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/scope-for-questions-about-terminology), and probably not yes/no questions like "Is X a good name for Y?". But it might be asking for suggestions on a concept that's not present in any other language.

Comment: Related: https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/38

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think naming of language constructs is an important part of the language's design, and so *would* be on-topic.

We might want a tag for these, so people who like naming thing can find questions to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think its okay so long as they are not easily findable on the web (ex. what should I call each letter - a character) or they aren't totally your opinion (ex.what should my cool new function be called - socoolfunction)

Comment: > what should I call a letter - a character
this is much more debated than you think, letters aren't always characters and characters aren't always letters